# Scrollbar is remaining the largest height after updating list contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to design a webpage that is to show about 700 rows from Database.

webpage is : http://www.shefacenter.ir/fa/disease

Data to show is: [Subject] & [Comment]

i get data from DB and show them simply in Unordered List (ul).

the code is like:

```
<div class="box_list_container">
<ul id='list_ngm' class='list_1column' >
<li><span>Subject</span><p class="list_comment">Comment</p></li>
<li><span>Subject</span><p class="list_comment">Comment</p></li>
<li><span>Subject</span><p class="list_comment">Comment</p></li>
...
<li><span>Subject</span><p class="list_comment">Comment</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

after that, i ADD some simple jQuery code to Switch Showing this List as 3 different Classes:

```
[Show Results in 1 Column List]
[Show Results in 2 Column List] 
[Show just Subjects of Results]
```

< this 3 mode has 3 different CSS class that they works fine. >

**NOW, My Problem Starts over here:**
when i switch showing results between that 3 modes, the Browser Scrollbar has Remains the Largest Height of List after switching.

Notice:
i have use "replaceWith" FROM "jquery-2.0.3.min.js" to change current Class of  for have a [1 column],[2 column] or [just subjects] show!

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I googled more and more to find my bad coding and solve the problem, just find that my problem goes from CSS codes. but i could not find right place of problem!! :-(

Comment: how do you hide the rows?

Comment: hi. hide them with $(".list_comment").hide();

Comment: it is tribble that nobody could help me to find and solve this problem!

Comment: i tried more and more, thus i found problem. i solve the problem. and there is no problem more!
thanks anybody who visit this page and who had write a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

i tried more and more to find the right way to solve that bad problem. 
and finally i found that.
the

tags, should have a "display:none" property at first. and after page loaded, with jQuery i change them to "display:block" . 
thats it!